# How to trim values in a field?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with field X on MS Access 2013. The values of X look something like this:

```
X
03100005000605
23656563554354
39994002200340
40100030100310
```

I want to trim these so only the first 4 digits are given. i.e.:

```
X-trim
0310
2365
3999
4010
```

From searching Google, I know there exists a 'LEFT' or 'RIGHT' function, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
select left(X, 4) as [X-Trim] from [table_name]
```

Comment: A good resource to review to help understand Alex K's answer can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms177601.aspx

Comment: Maybe `SELECT Left(X, 4) As [X-Trim] FROM [table_name]`

Comment: No maybe about it :) Muchas gracias, amigos!